# Parse Apache log in PHP using a sing named REGEX

Tags: regex, apache, logging

I stumbled upon this named-group regular expression rule, in which the author claims it that this single regular expression is capable of matching all possible outputs of one of the most widely used web servers in the world :

```html
(?:(?<network.srcIpv4>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|(?<network.srcIpv6>[:\-0-9a-fA-F]+?)|(?<network.srcHost>.+?)) - (?:-|(?<user.username>.+)) \[(?<time>.*)\]\"(?<application.cmd>(?<application.http.method>[A-Z]+)\s(?:(?<application.proto>.*?)://)?(?<network.fqdn>[ˆ/]*?)(?:\:(?<network.dstPort>d+))?(?<file.path>/.*?)?(?:\?(?<application.http.queryString>.*?))?(?: HTTP/(?<application.http.version>[0-9\.]+)?))\" (?<application.http.status>\d+) (?<application.len>\d+)(?:"(?:-|(?<application.http.referrer>.*))")?(?:"(?:-|(?<application.http.userAgent>.*))")?
```

but I when I tried it [here](https://regex101.com/), it didn't seem to be working. I know that it's possible to write a single regex to Apache logs, like this one :

```html
^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \[([^\]]+)\] "([A-Z]+)[^"]*" \d+ \d+ "[^"]*" "([^"]*)"$
```

but I prefer working with named regex, since they are easy to understand, can anybody help me figure out what is wrong with the first Regex ? Thanks.

PS: For the sake of argument, let's suppose I the regex be in PHP for example.

Comment: You canot use a `.` in the group name. It should start with `_` or an ASCII letter and then can have up to 31 word chars.

Comment: I have removed them, and tried again but it didn't work out. I think, the problem is something else.

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Jf4ac/2) with the `.` replaced with `_`, it works OK. What string do you need to match?

Comment: Well I have tried alot of examples, but they are not working ! 
`218.1.111.50 - - [13/Mar/2005:10:36:12 -0500] "GET http://www.yahoo.com/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2898 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 95)"`
Or
`24.23.244.160 - - [13/Mar/2005:13:48:40 -0500] "GET /scripts/..%25%35%63../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0" 404 1041 "-" "-"`

I don't know if you are familiar with the [sotM 34 challenge](http://old.honeynet.org/scans/scan34/). The source said that the previous named regular expression can catch all possible outputs of that dataset.

Comment: You have some typos in the pattern

Comment: Exactly, something is missing. I hope someone can find it. it took me hours without any progress !

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?<network_srcIpv4>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|(?<network_srcIpv6>[:\-0-9a-fA-F]+?)|(?<network_srcHost>.+?)) - (?:-|(?<user_username>.+)) \[(?<time>.*)\] \"(?<application_cmd>(?<application_http_method>[A-Z]+)\s(?:(?<application_proto>.*?)://)?(?<network_fqdn>[^/]*?)(?:\:(?<network_dstPort>\d+))?(?<file_path>/.*?)?(?:\?(?<application_http_queryString>.*?))?(?: HTTP/(?<application_http_version>[0-9\.]+)?))\" (?<application_http_status>\d+) (?<application_len>\d+) (?:"(?:-|(?<application_http_referrer>.*))")? (?:"(?:-|(?<application_http_userAgent>.*))")$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvxRTa/1).

Besides various typos in the regex (missing `\` before `\d` to match digits, `ˆ` instead of `^`) and missing spaces, the issue is that group names can only start with `_` or an ASCII letter and then can have up to 31 word chars. So, all `.` should be replaced with `_` or removed.

Note I added `^` and `$` line anchors (also note the `m` multiline modifier enabling that behavior). You may remove the anchors if you do not need a whole string/line match.

Comment: Thank you very match. You saved my day :).

EDIT !

This regex is intended to catch all possible access log outputs. I have tried it and it didn't catch **error logs** such as :

`[Sun Mar 13 10:36:11 2005] [error] [client 218.1.111.50] Directory index forbidden by rule: /var/www/html/`


or 

`[Mon Mar 07 00:07:01 2005] [error] Spurious SSL handshake interrupt [Hint: Usually just one of those OpenSSL confusions!?]`

Comment: @U.User Those are not following your regex. Just create  a new pattern for this style.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. I always could use the following, until I come up with an a named-group regex ! :

 `^\[([^\]]+)\] \[([^\]]+)\] (?:\[client ([^\]]+)\])?\s*(.*)$`